# VueJS implement go to prev menu

Tags: vue.js, menu, interaction

I am writing an app where a fixed length list gets generated based on the nested JSONArray. Whenever any elements gets clicked from the list and if it has a "sub data" array,the list gets populated with this "sub data". Basically, you can think of it as menus which has submenus and those submenus has subsubmenus and so on.

I have implemented two methods for going to sublevels [next()] which works fine but I don't know how to implement prev() method to go one level up in the menu. Currently, I can make it go one level up but if user is inside more than two level then I don't know how to keep the track of all above levels.

Here is the codepen -

[codepen](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/gjrBzr?editors=0011)

```
let JSONModel = (_id, _lvl, _title, _data) => {
  return {
    id: _id,
    lvl: _lvl,
    title: _title,
    data: _data
  };
};

let Menu = [
  {
    id: "01",
    lvl: "01",
    title: "menu 1",
    data: []
  },
  {
    id: "02",
    lvl: "01",
    title: "menu 2",
    data: []
  },
  {
    id: "03",
    lvl: "01",
    title: "menu 3",
    data: []
  },
  {
    id: "04",
    lvl: "01",
    title: "menu 4",
    data: [
      {
        id: "01",
        lvl: "02",
        title: "submenu 1",
        data: []
      },
      {
        id: "02",
        lvl: "02",
        title: "submenu 2",
        data: [
          {
            id: "01",
            lvl: "03",
            title: "sub submenu 1",
            data: []
          },
          {
            id: "02",
            lvl: "03",
            title: "sub submenu 2",
            data: []
          },
          {
            id: "03",
            lvl: "03",
            title: "sub submenu 3",
            data: []
          },
          {
            id: "04",
            lvl: "03",
            title: "sub submenu 4",
            data: []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "03",
        lvl: "02",
        title: "submenu 3",
        data: []
      },
      {
        id: "04",
        lvl: "02",
        title: "submenu 4",
        data: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

let demo = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    input: Menu,
    prevMenu:[]
  }, 
  computed: {},
  created: function () {  
  },
  methods: {
    next: function(val1,val2) {
      if (val1.length != 0) {
        this.input = val1;
        this.prevMenu = val2;
        console.log(this.prevMenu);
      }
    },
    prev: function() {
      console.log(this.prevMenu);
      this.input = this.prevMenu;
    }
  }
});

$("#prevmenu").on("click", function() {
  demo.prev();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, you can simply do this:
https://codepen.io/webkit_il/pen/bjebZR?editors=0011

```
next: function(val1,val2) {
      if (val1.length != 0) {
        this.input = val1;
        this.prevMenu.push(val2);
      }
    },
    prev: function() {
      let _menu = this.prevMenu.slice(); // this is just to clone the array
      this.input = _menu[_menu.length - 1];
      this.prevMenu.pop();
    }
```

changed your prevMenu into an array, then everytime you 
go back just use the last one, and remove it from the array...

good luck!

Comment: Thanks @webkit :)

Comment: can I ask one really simple question? Is this a good practice, the way I am doing it?

Comment: not really :), I'd probably avoid saving the whole menu everytime, maybe save an identifier (lvl?) I'm sure more optimization could be done, but it depends on the scope and context of your use case.

Comment: can you suggest some optimization? but thanks @webkit taking time to reply